# Windows Forms - How to return WMIC output into Textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, wmic

I'm new to coding (`3 days in and learning primarily from Google`) it's going well enough so far but now I'm stuck :)

I want to run a WMIC command and return the second line of the output into a textbox. The WMIC command is:

```
'WMIC bios get serialnumber'
```

This returns:

```
SerialNumber 
 ABCD1234
```

How do I get just the serial number into a textbox please?

Thanks...

Comment: do u get that Serial Number ABCD1234, to any textbox or label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to System.Management and use the following in your form method.

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
        ManagementObject obj = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();          

            textBox.Text =  (string)obj["SerialNumber"];
```